# Page managment in swing

Tags: java, swing, concurrency

So I have an array of JPanels, pages (fixed size) in my program. Each of them contains an array of JTextAreas.

User can use keyboard to add more JTextAreas, and they can be automatically resised when text is added or removed from them (their native behaviour, right).

What I need to implement (and I did, to some extent) is a code that will handle this events and move any JTextAreas that no longer fit a page onto the next one, and also, when some space is freed on a page, try to move content from the next page back onto that free space, if there's enough room. All in all, basic page managment stuff.

One of the first catches is that those changes can be vast enough that a couple of elements need to be moved.

What I did is added a filler object to the end of each page and attached a listener to it that gets triggerd everytime filler is resized, and it will resize when any of the above events occur.

The listener code natuarlly moves objects around.

Now, if I left everything like that, I would get one big mess. Listeners would be triggered all over the place in one big chain reaction everytime one of the above conditions were met.

Now, this is what I came up with so far (this code is only for when elements are shrunk or removed, code for addition is similar enough, no need to bother you with that).
This is called inside componentResized() method of the listener:

```
public void movingElements()
{
    //gets the new filler height to compare
    int newFillerHeight = getFiller().getHeight();

    //chapter contains an array of pages I need to deal with here
    Chapter chapter = getChapter();

    //element removed/shrunk
    //compares the oldFillerHeight which contains the height of the filler
    //prior to this particular resizing
    else if (newFillerHeight >= oldFillerHeight)
    {   
            //fetches the next and previous page of this page (getPage()
            //returns page we are dealing with)
        Page previousPage = chapter.getPreviousPage(getPage());
        Page nextPage = chapter.getNextPage(getPage());

            //here is where it gets tricky
            //I didn't want to check if first (few) element(s) can be
            //moved to previous page (which can happen if the first, large
            //element followed by several small ones is removed) (CHECK A) AND
            //if any elements on the next page can be moved to this one
            //(CHECK B). What I did instead was to always do the CHECK A.

            //if this is the first page of the chapter, I cannot perform the
            //CHECK A
        if (previousPage == null)
        {
                    //I have to invoke this method on the next page, if it
                    //exists. If it doesn't, then this is the only page of
                    //the chapter and I have nothing to do here.
            if (nextPage != null)
            {
                            //this is explained bellow this method
                nextPage.dummy.setVisible(true);
            }
        }

            //if previous page exists, we preform CHECK A
        else 
        {
            Element mover = getElement(1);

                    //I have to check if the first element on this page fits
                    //onto the free space of the previous one
                    //-2 is required to prevent infinite loops
            if (mover.getHeight() < previousPage.getFiller().getHeight()-2)
            {
                            //I move the element
                removeElement(mover);
                previousPage.addElement(mover, previousPage.getElementCount()+1);

                            //This is a flag that tells that an object was
                            //moved, you'll se why I need it soon enough
                chapter.setMoved(true);
            }

                    //If I can't move the object, I have move onto the next
                    //page (if it exists) and repeat the process. I also
                    //check for isMoved flag because maybe nothing was moved
                    //on the previous page and there is no need to keep the
                    //this chain of execution going
            else if ((nextPage != null) && (chapter.isMoved()))
            {
                            //sets isMoved flag to false so the above code
                            //would work
                            chapter.setMoved(false);
                nextPage.dummy.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    //saves the new filer height for further use
    oldFillerHeight = newFillerHeight;
}
```

Note: Element is a class that extends a JPanel and has JTextArea in it, which dictates it's height.

Here's what the dummy is all about:

```
dummy = new JPanel();
dummy.setVisible(false);

dummy.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0)
    {
            dummy.setVisible(false);
        movingElements();   
    }           
});
```

What this does is ensures that everyting is repainted when movingElements() is invoked next time. If I invoked it straight from itslef, it would go of before the filler could update it's height, messing things up.

I don't know if this is the right way of doing it, it seemed simplest, howevery complex it may look.

But now I need to somehow make sure that this method is never called from the listener before it's execution chain is completed. I also don't need the user to do something to make two of these run parallel, so I'd like to block user completely until the chain is done. This is all done very fast, but still...

So, Is this the right way of doing it, or should I resort to some other way?
How can I ensure that only one chain is running at the time?

EDIT:

Sorry for the code formating, tabbing looks really nice in the edit box but it's all messed up in the display...

EDIT2:

I solved it, this is what I did:

Filler code:

```
filler.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0)
        {   
            if (!getChapter().isChaining())
            {
                getChapter().setChaining(true);
                movingElements();
            }

            oldFillerHeight = getFiller().getHeight();
        }
    });
```

Dummy code:

```
dummy.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0)
        {
            dummy.setVisible(false);
            movingElements();
        }           
    });
```

movingElements() method:

```
public void movingElements()
{
    int newFillerHeight = getFiller().getHeight();
    Document document = getDocument();
    Chapter chapter = getChapter();

    //element added/enlarged
    if (newFillerHeight == 0)
    {   
        Page nextPage = chapter.getNextPage(getPage());

        if (nextPage == null)
        {
            nextPage = new Page();
            chapter.addPage(nextPage, chapter.getPageIndex(getPage())+1);
        }

        Element mover = getPage().getElement(getPage().getElementCount());

        removeElement(mover);
        nextPage.addElement(mover, 1);

        getPage().dummy.setVisible(true);
    }

    //element removed/shrunk
    else if (newFillerHeight >= oldFillerHeight)
    {   
        Page previousPage = chapter.getPreviousPage(getPage());
        Page nextPage = chapter.getNextPage(getPage());

        if (previousPage == null)
        {
            if (nextPage != null)
            {
                nextPage.dummy.setVisible(true);
            }

            else
            {
                //chain end
                chapter.setChaining(false);
            }
        }

        else 
        {
            Element mover = getElement(1);

            if (mover.getHeight() < previousPage.getFiller().getHeight()-2)  //-2 is required to prevent infinite loops
            {
                removeElement(mover);
                previousPage.addElement(mover, previousPage.getElementCount()+1);

                chapter.setMoved(true);

                getPage().dummy.setVisible(true);
            }

            else if ((nextPage != null) && (chapter.isMoved()))
            {
                nextPage.dummy.setVisible(true);
            }

            else
            {
                //chain end
                chapter.setChaining(false);
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        //chain end
        chapter.setChaining(false);
    }
}
```

And I added this to chapter, the owner of all pages:

```
private AtomicBoolean chaining= new AtomicBoolean(false);

public boolean isChaining()
{
    return chaining.get();
}

public void setChaining(boolean chaining)
{
    this.chaining.set(chaining);
}
```

I will probably add keyboard input blocker and unblocker to this two methods.

Comment: did you thinking about JPanel with JTextArea or JTextArea in JTable with only one column, with or without JTable Header

Comment: I need the GUI to look like a MSWord document. At least as far as the pages go.

If you are asking for the Element object, it can have several versions, but only importaint this is that it contains a JTextArea that dictates its height.

I didn't use any JTables any anything related to them...

Comment: What should happen if a JTextArea is bigger than the page itself?

Comment: I created a custom DocumentFilter to prevent user from entering enough characters to come to that...

Comment: -1 again, for again not providing a SSCCE. Questions like this simply can't be answered without, there are too many possibilities of what might go wrong (especially when coded against the grain)

Comment: I'm just asking is this is a good concept of if it can be done any other way and how to deal with concurency here. I'm not asking for a bug fix. There is absolutley no need for SSCCE. This is either good way or it's not. If it's not, suggest me an alternative. I'm not asking to code it for me but to say to try to use *some Java feature I am unaware of*. Or don't us filler, use Java.sun.pageManagment library. I'm not asking for exact solutions but a general path. And for that you don't need to execute the code, you only need to know how it's supposed to work.

Comment: What's wrong with a big chain reaction? That's what's supposed to happen when there is movement in one page. For example, if a JTextArea is moved to the previous page, that page has to check if it can pull content from the next page, and so on until a page can't do it.
The reason why this feels clunky is probably because of the existence of the JTextAreas. I'd implement the page system over the classes needed to do an "advanced text editor" and see what are my options with these. For example, mantain the page boundaries as simple indexes within the "String" that is the content.

Comment: Thing is that that Element is a class that is never initalized, but always extended. There are Question and Answer classes that extend it. Answer is actually stacked inside the Question which is stacked on the page. This makes the moving easier since I don't want to break up the question with it's answers over two pages. But it doesn't contain just JTextareas but some other important elements, but ot for this particular situation. Their widths and heights of some objects that contain need to be precise to a single pixel.
I's a WYSIWYG editor, and everyting need to be precise.

Comment: Besides, I'm used to geting my ideas shot down and being told I'm doing things the wrong way. And that tricky with dummy seemed like a workaround of that kind...

Comment: I'd rather do something independent of the UI events, like everytime there is a height_change/insert/remove call a method that solves this problem:
"Given a list of integers (JTextAreas height) put them in cells (pages), in the given order, filling each cell as much as possible, without surpassing the maximum cell capacity (page height)". Which is trivial. And then if you moved something around update the UI.

Comment: Isn't "height_change/insert/remove" an UI event?

Comment: Well it's actually a document event, but what I meant is that you don't rely upon a listener chain reaction to update subsequent pages. The first one will be updated by an event one way or another of course.

Answer (score 1):

http://java-sl.com/Pagination_In_JEditorPane.html may be this could halep with pagination.

For your case (text without formatting in `JTextArea`) I would use just one `JTextArea` and changed the `View` (`WrappedPlainView` or just `PlainView`) to render pages.

Comment: I've read that already. I doesn't work for me, I need the bunch of JTextAreas to make it more clear to the user where to put what. It's like he's filling a dynamic form. But thanks anyway for the suggestion...

Comment: I used to work with somthing like this (multiple related JComponents  - linked textboxes) and it was really problem. I would recomment to have just one model and represent it in _one_ view with all visual effects.