# Concurrency mechanic for a particular situation

Tags: java, concurrency

The situation is this one (look below EDIT2):

[SITUATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719715/page-managment-in-swing)

I have a method (method A) that will cycle trught components one by one and remove them if they meet a criteria which will will trigger the event (my little method chain reaction) that the question above is dealing with.

I have an AtomicBoolean which will be true while that chain is executing and will turn false when it's done or not executing, which method A can access.

Now, I know where exactly method A would trigger the event (it would trigger it when removing objects), so I can set the AtomicBoolean to true manually from method A.

Now all I need to do is PAUSE the method untill AtomicBoolean turns false.

I can't use PropertyChangeListener because I can plop it in the middle of method and use it to pause it, I'd have to break up my method to smaller ones, which I cannot do,

If Lock class is something that could work here, I'm failling to see how.

Basically, what I need this:

```
while (AtomicBoolean)
{
    Thread.sleep(0);
}
```

but written in a smarter form, so it wouldn't torture the processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa a `CountDownLatch` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) and trigger it once your checking thread has finished.

Thread 1 (doing the work):

```
CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);
// ...
signal.countDown();
```

Thread 2 (waiting for the other thread having done its work):

```
//..
// await will block until the other thread triggers countDown
signal.await();
//done
```